# Why can't this class be found with this CSS selector?

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to use either an xpath shortcut or a css selector to find all objects on the page that fit this:

```py
<span class="perWord ng-binding">$0.20</span>
```

I am struggling to understand selectors but I have tried:

```py
(Pdb) selector.css('.perWord').getall()
[]
(Pdb) selector.css('.perWord')
[]
(Pdb) selector.css('perWord')
[]
(Pdb) selector.css('ng-binding')
[]
(Pdb) selector.css('perWord ng-binding')
[]
(Pdb) selector.css('.perWord_ng-binding')
[]
(Pdb) selector.css('.ng-binding').getall()
['<title ng-bind-template="100 Days In Appalachia | Who Pays Writers? " class="ng-binding">100 Days In Appalachia | Who Pays Writers? </title>', '<div ng-bind="venue.name" class="pull-left ng-binding">100 Days In Appalachia</div>', '<div class="pull-right small grayLighter ng-binding"> report<span ng-bind="GrammarHelper.pluralS(interactions.length)" class="ng-binding"></span> </div>', '<span ng-bind="GrammarHelper.pluralS(interactions.length)" class="ng-binding"></span>']
```

This is the website and code I am using:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://whopayswriters.com/#/publication/100-days-in-appalachia')
selector = Selector(text = driver.page_source)
pdb.set_trace()
```

I expect to give all five instances that apear on the page:

```py
<span class="perWord ng-binding">$0.20</span>
```

Comment: content is loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Succeeded for me using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://whopayswriters.com/#/publication/100-days-in-appalachia')
time.sleep(3)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("perWord")
```

if you want try to add `time.sleep(3)` to your code, because sometimes the page is not loaded yet, so the elements cannot be found.

Comment: Hmm I just tried it and it works for me too. Do you know why the scrappy selector doesn't work?

Comment: @DavidHampton the webpage uses JS and some of the content loads asyncronously so scrapy's request gets the initial content before everything is loaded and the desired elements are not there. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

That data is dynamically added from an xhr call returning json. Using `requests` alone is sufficient. You can calculate the per word of the returned json. The call can be found in the network tab. You can add in id from json if you need to be able to link back.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://whopayswriters.com/reports/public?design=cf&view=interaction_venues&key=%22f6c531bac691fa7846cb0b0c4b081a08%22&reduce=false&include_docs=true').json()
per_word = ['$' + str(round(int(i['doc']['compensation']['Stipend / Honoraria / Fee'].replace('$',''))/i['doc']['pieceLength'],2)) for i in r['rows']]
print(per_word)
```

For example, you could link to feature length:

```
per_word = {i['doc']['pieceLength']:'$' + str(round(int(i['doc']['compensation']['Stipend / Honoraria / Fee'].replace('$',''))/i['doc']['pieceLength'],2)) for i in r['rows']}
print(per_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `WebDriverWait` or use `sleep` in your code for increasing the loading time of the specific request.

Also, it is a dynamic request so none of the elements is present in the page source. So scrappy selector won't find the elements in the response. You should use some methods which handle dynamic requests such as `selenium, splash` etc